# How to fix TimeDistributed input shape problem (need 5 dimension)

Tags: python, keras, valueerror

I am trying to create human action recognition model. But when I try to add TimeDistributed feature, I have an input_shape problem. How can I convert input_shape from 4d to 5d?

I want to train my dataset with each 10 images, in order to understand actions.

Dataset size= (28000,90,90,1)

```
#define CNN model
cnn = Sequential()
cnn.add(Conv2D(filters=32,kernel_size= 
(5,5),padding="Same",activation="relu",input_shape=(90,90,1)))
cnn.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
cnn.add(Dropout(0.25))

cnn.add(Conv2D(filters=16,kernel_size=(5,5),padding="Same",activation="relu"))
cnn.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
cnn.add(Dropout(0.25))

cnn.add(Conv2D(filters=32,kernel_size=(5,5),padding="Same",activation="relu"))
cnn.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
cnn.add(Dropout(0.25))

cnn.add(Flatten())
cnn.add(Dense(4096, activation="relu"))

#define LSTM model
model = Sequential()
model.add(TimeDistributed(cnn,input_shape=(10,90,90,1)))
model.add(LSTM(10))
model.add(Dense(2, activation="softmax"))

verbose, epochs, batch_size = 0, 25, 64
optimizer=Adam(lr=0.001,beta_1=0.9,beta_2=0.999)
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer,loss="binary_crossentropy",metrics=["accuracy"])
model.fit(x_train, y_train,validation_data=(x_val,y_val), epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size)
```

Here the error:
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected time_distributed_8_input to have 5 dimensions, but got array with shape (28000, 90, 90)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I'm using Tensorflow.keras from TensorFlow 2.0 alpha. My input data was formed in the following way:
`(list, list, numpy.ndarray, numpy.ndarray, numpy.ndarray)` corresponding to `number of records in batch, number of timesteps, img_width, img_height, channels`.

Turns out the Tensorflow input-shape-validation code actually misses the case where the input shape of a given record is built from a `list` containing `numpy arrays`, and the `list` dimension is stripped off. It does handle almost every other formation of the data.

I modified the Tensorflow library code locally to fix it and have reported the fix (https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/28323, which I hope to fix and submit to TF this week).

That said - I think if you change your input data set into a form consisting of `(list, numpy.ndarray, numpy.ndarray, numpy.ndarray, numpy.ndarray)` it may solve the issue you're having.